# Turn polynomial into another form by using synthetic division

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

$$f(x) = 8(x-\frac{1}{2})^3+16(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+6(x-\frac{1}{2})+7$$
How do I turn the above polynomial into the form shown below by using synthetic division?
$$f(x) = a(2x-1)^3+b(2x-1)^2+c(2x-1)+d$$

And also how do I solve for a, b, c, d?

Comment: Your polynomial is already on that form. Just multiply and divide by $2^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that $$x-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2x-1}{2}$$ and so on and $$\frac{(2x-1)^3}{2^3}=\frac{(2x-1)^3}{8}$$